# Reduce if condition in python to avoid duplicate operations in a single function

Tags: python

I have the below function where i check the value of `list_of_files` based on the last character of the each `x_id` string.
For each if condition i have to give the same operation in a single function to return.

Is there a way to assign the value of `list_of_files` once based on the `x_id`and avoid duplicating the `same_operation()`

Code Below :

```
def custm(x_code,x_id,x_date, list_of_files):
    x_code = self.getcode()
    x_id  = self.getid()       
    x_date =self.getdate()

    if list(x_id)[-1] == '0':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[0]
        some_operation()
        return some_operation
    if list(x_id)[-1] == '1':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[1]
        some_operation()
        return some_operation
    if list(x_id)[-1] == '2':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[2]
        some_operation()
        return some_operation
    if list(x_id)[-1] == '3':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[3]
        some_operation()
        return some_operation
```

Comment: The some_operation method is independent from list_of_files?

Comment: Did you mean `return some_operation()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a for loop with enumerate

```
last_id = list(x_id)[-1]
for idx, number in enumerate("0123"):
    if last_id == number:
        list_of_files = list_of_files[idx]
        some_operation()
        return some_operation
```

Since you're returning from each if statement, you'd only be assigning once anyway regardless of this change

Comment: Did you mean `return some_operation()`?

Comment: @DeepSpace - Thats the same as the op's code... since its pseudo code i chose to leave it as written

Answer (score 1):

You can directly cast the number string into an int and use that to index.
just to make sure that it will always work you may want to do it in a `try` ... `catch` insert to find cases where it doesn't work

EX:

```
def custm(x_code,x_id,x_date, list_of_files):
    x_code = self.getcode()
    x_id  = self.getid()       
    x_date =self.getdate()


    i = int(list(x_id)[-1]) #cast the string of the number into the actual number
    if i in range(1,5): #condition if list(x_id)[-1] can be bigger than 4
                        # as suggested by @FBruzzesi
        list_of_files = list_of_files[i] # use the number
        some_operation()
        return some_operation
```

Comment: Maybe OP also need a condition on i being less than 4 - It's not really clear from the question

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify it like this

```
def custm(x_code,x_id,x_date, list_of_files):
    x_code = self.getcode()
    x_id  = self.getid()       
    x_date =self.getdate()

    if list(x_id)[-1] == '0':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[0]
    elif list(x_id)[-1] == '1':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[1]
    elif list(x_id)[-1] == '2':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[2]
    elif list(x_id)[-1] == '3':
        list_of_files = list_of_files[3]
    else
        return

    some_operation()
    return some_operation
```